# Windows wubi installer

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, wubi

So while installing windows on my system a few months ago I left ~40 GB to install ubuntu later and now I wanna do it,so is there any way I can use the Windows Installer to install ubuntu on that unpartitioned free space or I need to install it in the old fashioned way on my current windows installation

Answer (score 1):

WUBI won't work for you in this situation. WUBI makes a disk image file on your Windows partition to store the Ubuntu OS and then mounts the disk image when you choose to boot Ubuntu. This gives the benefit of trying Ubuntu without needing to Repartition the HDD and only suffer some very minor limitations. Plus it let's you remove Ubuntu like it was a regular old program.

Since you already Partitioned the Space ahead of time you might as well use it. Burn an Ubuntu Installer DVD or make a Bootable USB and then just install Ubuntu using that.

Comment: The OP can always make an NTFS partition on the free space from within Windows and use Wubi to install there.

Comment: I'd never install Ubuntu on a NTFS partition. Linux and NTFS get along only grudgingly and usually permission problems occure. For Ubuntu definitely go with an EXT4 partition for the Root Filesystem and Home folder. You'll save yourself much grief.

Comment: No, I'm talking about Wubi since it needs to be installed on a Windows-writable FS for boot chaining. The full install, definitely EXT4. Wubi is best on NTFS since the bootloader is used to grief, :)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. But really if he was planning on installing Ubuntu anyway there's no reason to make a Temporary setup using Wubi. They aren't major but their are some good cons to Wubi. Anyway, since the Partition space is already prepared there's no risk to installing Ubuntu like normal. If he doesn't like it he can simply delete the Partition, that simple.